# Reading from a CSV file and solving problems with ";"

Tags: c, csv, scanf, delimiter

I have this CSV file and I have to read it and print each different customer (each line is a customer)

```
IDClient;Name;Surname;Address;City;State;Postal_Code
111A;Howard;Snyder;2732 Baker Blvd.;Eugene;OR;97403
222B;Yoshi;Latimer;City Center Plaza 516 Main St.;Elgin;OR;97827
333C;John;Steel;12 Orchestra Terrace;Walla Walla;WA;99362
444D;Jaime;Yorres;87 Polk St. Suite 5;San Francisco;CA;94117
```

I wrote this code and despite some warnings seems to work except for some trouble with `;`

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("clientes.txt", "rt");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("File is open\n");
        printCustomers(fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}


void printCustomers (FILE *fp) 
{
    char id[5], first [8], last [10], adress[17], city[12], state[3], zip[6];
    printf("Printing.\n");
    fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL); //Skip first line
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    while (fscanf(fp,"%4s %7s %9s %16[^\n] %11[^\n] %2s %5s", &id, &first, &last, &adress, &city, &state, &zip) == 7)
    {
        printf("IdClient: %s\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nAdress: %s\nCity: %s\nState: %s\nZip: %s\n", id, first, last, adress, city, state, zip);
        printf("-----------------------\n");
    }

}
```

My output is this, as you can see the `;` are ruining the output. I think this can be solved with the fscanf formatting but I don't know how can I do it.

```
 -----------------------
    IdClient: 111A
    Name: ;Howard
    Surname: ;Snyder;2
    Adress: 732 Baker Blvd.;
    City: Eugene;OR;9
    State: 74
    Zip: 03
    -----------------------
    IdClient: 222B
    Name: ;Yoshi;
    Surname: Latimer;C
    Adress: ity Center Plaza
    City: 516 Main St
    State: .;
    Zip: Elgin
    -----------------------
    IdClient: ;OR;
    Name: 97827
    Surname: 333C;John
    Adress: ;Steel;12 Orches
    City: tra Terrace
    State: ;W
    Zip: alla
    -----------------------
    IdClient: Wall
    Name: a;WA;99
    Surname: 362
    Adress: 444D;Jaime;Yorre
    City: s;87 Polk S
    State: t.
    Zip: Suite
    ----------------------
```

If I didn't explain myself well or something is missing please tell me.

Output has to be like that for each customer, maybe with my current fscanf it's a bit hard to reach this because not all fields have same length on each customer:

```
-----------------------
IdClient: 111A
Name: Howard
Surname: Snyder
Adress: 2732 Baker Blvd.
City: Eugene
State: OR
Zip: 97403
-----------------------
```

Comment: The "C"in "CSV" stands for "comma", not "semicolon".

Comment: Yep, it's true I thought the same and told my teacher but he still called it a CSV file ;) Anyways differences are ridiculous, it's just change comma for  a semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your code

```
 fscanf(fp,"%4s %7s %9s %16[^\n] %11[^\n] %2s %5s",...
```

to the style

```
fscanf(fp,"%4s;%7[^;];%10[^;];......
```

to have the `;`s as a part of the *format string*. Then it won't be considered as a part of the *string input*.

---

**Note:** The above method is just a *workaround* and will break easily if the format is changed. Suggested generic approach to achieve the same in a much robust way:

1. Read a whole line using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. Tokenize using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) using the `;` as delimiter.
3. >>[Optional]<< If required, for any field, convert the token to `int` using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)
4. Print the result.
5. continue untill `strtok()` returns NULL.

Comment: But will that really cause `%s` to "look ahead" and stop at the first `;` it finds? I think not.

Comment: This is assuming he wants `;` in the format, but OP has not clarified.

Comment: @SouravGhosh See @BLUEPIXY's comment, that's what I was hinting at. Also I don't understand the `%[^\n]` part, there's no multi-line fields in a CSV file AFAIK.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have updated, but not very sure, as I am not comfortable with `scanf()` family while parsing. I use the second approach. Can you please check the `fscanf()` update in my asnwer and make any changes, if required? Thank you.

Comment: I edited and added how has to be output. Thanks for all answers guys.

Comment: I think I will go with your suggestion note, seems a much better solution. I will try it as soon as I understand how can I use the strtok().

Comment: @RBNMUSTDIE you can start by checking the manual page in the link in my answer. :-)